Do I meet the conditions of GPLv3 license?
GitHub says GPLv3 licence conditions are:

License and copyright notice
State changes
Disclose source
Same license

License and copyright notice: How do I write copyright notice? Is it enough to write " © Riverbank Computing Limited" in README file?
State changes: I won't write state changes because I won't change anything in PyQt6.
Disclose source: I will note that I used PyQt6 in my project and link to PyPI address in README.
Same license: Since PyQt6 is released under GPLv3, I have to use GPLv3 license when I use it in my project, right?
Am I doing right?

Rather than Github's summary, have you read the GPL itself? It's somewhat wordy but should answer most of your questions. If it doesn't, please clarify exactly which bits you need assistance with.

If you're doing this as work for your employer, I'd strongly suggest talking to more experienced people at your employer. If your employer doesn't have any more experienced people, they should get professional advice. "Some folks on Stack Exchange told me this was okay" won't hold up in court if you do get it wrong.

@PhilipKendall I'm doing this as open-source hobby project.

Well, in that case you certainly don't want to put "© Riverbank Computing Limited"!

I am asking if I am doing right.

Do you want to GPL your code? If you don't want to do that, then I would consider PySide instead (which is LGPL licensed and which serves a similar purpose to PyQt).

GitHub doesn't really explain a license. For a simplified explanation, check out https://fossa.com/blog/open-source-software-licenses-101-gpl-v3/
